# Computerized method and system for recipe presentation

Tags: prior-art-request, mobile, network, audio, us20080300993

Aren't bunch of [claims](http://www.google.com/patents/US20080300993) related to javascript onsubmit/onchange functionality, and normal web communication? It's just ridiculous. Also, prior art cites plain recipe search sites, but not recipes by ingredients sites, like cocktailbuilder.com. Also, using phone to interact with communication, and voice? Are these things new art???

Comment: Welcome to Ask Patents. There is no document number in your post so no one can help. It may be that you are looking at an application for a patent not a granted patent. People can apply for anything - it doesn't mean they will get it.

Comment: Yes, it still has application status as the link shows. Didn't realize this site is only for published patents, but thought it is also for preventing bad ones from being published.

Comment: This site *is* for helping bad patent applications from turning into bad patents. The publishing of an application does not indicate any level of acceptance and is automatic regardless of content as long as the formal requirements are met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The patent-application looks like a description of an actual implementation of a cooking website. What he is trying to patent is not "..javascript onsubmit/onchange functionality.." but the functionality of the website as a whole.

The key here is that this is an "application" for a patent and it is not "granted".

Looking at the USPTO [PAIR database](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) you can see the history of the examination of the application, which shows that it was initially rejected in 2009, and then finally abandoned in 2010 when the applicant failed to follow up on the initial rejection.

[image]

Hence there is no patent grant of this application and there never will be a grant.